# Adding project dependencies in a multi project Buildship workspace

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have two projects, `client` and `shared`. Both are Buildship projects and have external dependencies defined and working. Here's my multi project setup:

```
workspace/
    shared/
        build.gradle
    client/
        build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

`workspace/settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'workspace'

include 'client'
include 'shared'
```

Now I want to sort inter-project dependencies. `client` depends on compiled artifacts from `shared`. So according to [25.4.3. Project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:project_dependencies) I think I add the following to `client`s `build.gradle`:

```
compile project(':shared')
```

However I can't compile in Eclipse. If I refresh the `client` project I get:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'client'. Project with path
>   ':shared' could not be found in root project 'client'.

It's like it doesn't recognise it as a multi project build...

I realised that `gradle init` had generated a `settings.gradle` file inside the two child projects. So I removed those files, but then I get a different error when refreshing either child project (and the project becomes entirely unusable):

> Provided eclipse project is not the root project

How to get the two projects to work together, and hopefully just define this once?

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to help here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/multi-project-builds/21025/8) the following should fix it:

1. Delete the `client` and `shared` projects from Eclipse, leave the files intact on the file system
2. Move the root folder with `client` and `shared` inside to a different folder, so the root folder is *not* also the Eclipse workspace root
3. Perform a Gradle import inside Eclipse for the root folder

That fixed it for me - inter project dependencies were then resolved.

Comment: Could you clarify this post with a description of your final directory layout?

Comment: Sorry - I don't have this anymore.

Comment: No problem, my issue turned out to be that my version of buildship didn't support java 14 yet